# How to run selenium code

Tags: selenium

I have the code written for selenium, but I do not know how to make selenium read the code. I know that you have to put it in a certain folder somewhere though. I have never used this program or anything like it before. I just need to know how to make selenium read my code. I have no idea what I'm doing here.

```
public class GoogleTest {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    String baseUrl = "google.com";;
    Selenium selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, baseUrl);
    selenium.open("google.com");
    selenium.type("name=q", "cheese");
    selenium.click("name=btnG");
    WebDriver driverInstance = ((WebDriverBackedSelenium) selenium).getUnderlyingWebDriver();
}
```

Comment: What language are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: I am using Java and writing in BlueJ. I have no idea what to do so I do not know what to try

Comment: Have you tried using Maven, like this? http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#setting-up-a-selenium-webdriver-project

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the following line before creating the driver object:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/path/to/chrome/driver/chrome.exe");
```

Try following code in same order:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    String baseUrl = "google.com";;
    Selenium selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, baseUrl);
    .
    .
```

You may need to download the chrome driver as well. 
link: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver